# setting margins with R hexbin/grid

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a plot which has to be in EPS format with R.  I have to use hexbin, as there are too many points to plot using normal methods in R.

The problem is that the traditional margin-altering commands in R no longer work when you use this, R simply ignores them (and doesn't tell you it's ignoring them)

How can I alter this code

```
library(hexbin)
x <- read.delim('scatter.tsv', sep="\t")
bin <- hexbin(x[,1], x[,2], xbins = 500)
setEPS()
postscript('debug.eps')
plot(bin, legend=FALSE, colramp=BTY, xlab ='this will be the xlabel', ylab = 'this will be the ylabel', main= 'this is the title')
dev.off()
```

to make the vertical axis label in the figure below not overlap with the tick labels?

[image]

Comment: Probably the quickest / easiest route is to use `ylab = 'this will be the ylabel\n\n'` . [ps might be worth changing your example to `bin <- hexbin(rnorm(10000, 10000), rnorm(10000, 10000), xbins = 500)` so it is reproducible]

Comment: @user20650 that indeed worked.  I don't know how I can mark your answer as what solved the problem, though.